# 2 domains 1 adfs

Tags: 2016, adfs, domain, claims

I have a SharePoint Farm on Domain A

And a ADFS Server on Domain B

I have to enable adfs authenticaton on A, and to make it work with B.

So far, I have been able to do so, but now I have an error message saying that "The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm".

I have checked the claims configuration and it should be good, but before going further, I would like to know if it may be caused by the fact that both environments aren't on the same domain ?

Thank you

Comment: have you check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alextch/2011/06/27/establishing-federation-trust/